# Dynamically Generating SQL Queries with Python and SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Below is a generalisation of my problem:

Consider the table

```
    ID    A    B    C
r1  1     1    0    1
.   .     .    .    .
.   .     .    .    .
.   .     .    .    .
rN  N     1    1    0
```

Where the columns `A,B,C` contain either `0` or `1`. I am trying to write a python function that takes a list of permutations of `0`'s and `1`'s, generates a query that will passed to SQLite3 that then counts the number of records that have `A,B,C` in one of these permutations.

For example if I passed the following list to my function `permList = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0]]`, then it would count all records with the `[A,B,C]` combination as either `[1,0,1]` or `[1,0,0]`.

Currently I am doing it like this

```
def permCount(permList):
    SQLexpression = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE "

    for i in range(len(permList)):
        perm = permList[i]
        SQLexpression += "(A=" + str(perm[0]) + " AND B=" + str(perm[1]) + 
                      " AND C=" + str(perm[2]) + ")"
        if i!=len(permList)-1:
            SQLexpression += " OR "

    *Execute SQLexpression and return answer*
```

Now this is fine but it seems like a bit of a fiddle. Is there a better way to dynamically generate the SQL queries where the length of input `permList` is unknown?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def permCount(permList):
    condition = ' OR '.join(['(A=? AND B=? AND C=?)' 
                             for row in permList])
    sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE {c}".format(
        c=condition)
    args = sum(permList, [])
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Use [parametrized SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). That means instead of inserting the values with string formatting, use placemarkers (e.g. `?`), and then supply the arguments as the second *argument* to `cursor.execute`.

This is easier code and prevents [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes in your main for loop, to make use of pythons generators and list comprehension features.

```
def permCount(permList):

SQLexpression = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE "

for perm in permList:    # if you need the i for other reason, you could write:
                         # for i, perm in enumerate(permList)

    a, b, c = [str(_) for _ in perm]

    SQLexpression += "(A=" + a + " AND B=" + b + \
                  " AND C=" + c + ") OR "

SQLexpression = SQLexpression[:-4] + ";"   # Trim the last " OR "
```